# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyathena' when running AWS Glue Job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue, pyathena

Despite setting the parameter for my Python AWS Glue Job like this:

```
--additional-python-modules pyathena
```

I still get the following error when I try and run the job:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyathena'
```

I have also tried the following parameters:

```
--additional-python-modules pyathena
--pip-install pyathena
--pip-install pyathena==2.23.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone finds themselves with a similar issue this is what worked for me.

I solved this issue by removing the '--additional-python-modules pyathena' argument and upgrading the AWS Glue Job Python version to 3.9 (where pyathena is automatically installed as part of the default analytics package).

As I understand it, the --additional-python-modules argument does not work with earlier versions of AWS Glue Python.